# Possible to bind StatusBar or ControlTip control source in Access?

Tags: ms-access

I have a subform in datasheet view and due to monitor size restriction, I cannot fit all the columns in a desired length. I also want to avoid unnecessary extra textboxes on main form which would be linked the the 'too narrow columns'.

Hence I want to display the current field.value to the user somehow. I know I can write some comment to statusBar or controlTip, but how can I dynamically change this to represent the actual value in the field of the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't really be done well.
You can set both properties at runtime, but when?

The best (or least bad) solution is to ask the user to click into the field where he wants to see the full value. The main effect here is to set the current record, so the correct values will be displayed.

```vb
Private Sub myTextBox_GotFocus()

    Me.myTextBox.ControlTipText = Me.myTextBox.Value
    ' or
    SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, Me.myTextBox.Value

End Sub
```

There is also the MouseMove event, which looks much better at first:

```
Private Sub myText_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
```

But you'd have to determine the record the mouse is moved over to show the correct values. And you can't use X and Y for calculations with section heights and record counts, because the coordinates are local to the control (textbox).